# Swift - endIndex.predecessor()

Tags: swift, string

Do these comments make any sense ?
Trying to figure out why it removes the character of my reversed given string, instead of the regular given string in this case.

```
import Foundation

extension String {
  func reverseWords() -> String {
    var result = ""

    let words = self.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    for thisWord in words.reverse() {
        result += thisWord + " "
    }

    print("..\(result)..") 
// Result is the words array ( contains self ) reversed with seperator " "

    print("..\(self)..")

    result.removeAtIndex(self.endIndex.predecessor()) 
// So here i am checking self within result?, and am removing the last index
// of my currently reversed given string inside result?
// I do result in my intended last space removal with result.endIndex but i'm
// wondering what happens in this case with the self.endIndex :)

    return result

  }
}

var str = "This string contains a few elements"
str.reverseWords()
```

Comment: By the way, you can simplify the logic by calling `return words.reverse().joinWithSeparator(" ")`.

Comment: Compare https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1539571-endindex: `endIndex` is the “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` still refers to the original unreversed `String`.

The correct code would be:

```
result.removeAtIndex(result.endIndex.predecessor())
```

You should never use a `String` index for another string. If you are indexing `result`, you shouldn't use an index from `self`.

With a simple string you won't seem a difference but if you start adding multi-byte characters, e.g. emojis, your application can crash.

For example, using `result += thisWord + ""` would result in:

> elementsfewacontainsstring�This

with `self.endIndex`

and

> elementsfewacontainsstringThis

with `result.endIndex`.

`endIndex` is the index past the end of the `String`. It works the same as `count` for arrays. `count` in arrays doesn't represent the last element, `count - 1` represents the last element.

If your aim is to change the original `String`, you have to declare the method as `mutating` and assign to `self`, e.g.:

```
mutating func reverseWords() {
    var result = ""

    let words = self.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    for thisWord in words.reverse() {
        result += thisWord + " "
    }

    self = result
    self.removeAtIndex(self.endIndex.predecessor())
}
```

although that's rather uncommon in functional programming.

Comment: He knows it should be `...result.endIndex...`. OP is asking what happens if `self` is used instead.

Comment: But does the self inside :

    result.removeAtIndex(self.endIndex.predecessor())

Refer to the self inside result?

Comment: @CeraMo69 no, self is consistent throughout the whole function body, always pointing to the implicit parameter on which `reverseWords` was called

Comment: @CeraMo69: It may work here by pure chance if the `self` and `result` have   the same number of characters. But generally, it is undefined behaviour, as stated in this answer (+1).

Comment: @CeraMo69 Yes, imagine `String` as an array of bytes where `String.Index` represents a character index. With 1-byte characters (ASCII, English characters) the `endIndex` represents just the number of characters which is the same in `self` and in `result`. So it will work. In a `String` with multi-byte characters, it will break easily.

Comment: So here it takes the index count of self, and subtracts one off that count which results in subtracting two off result since self contains one less in this case? Or close

Comment: @CeraMo69 Yes. To show it on a more complex `String`, if you look at my example with emojis, every ASCII character has length 1 and every emoji has length 2. The original string with no emojis has length `35` and it has `35` bytes. `endIndex` in that case represents byte index `35` and `endIndex().predecessor` represents byte index `34`. The reversed string with emojis contains `35` characters but its byte length is `40` (it has five emojis). If you now try to remove the element at index `self.endIndex().predecessor` which is `34`, it will remove 1 byte of an emoji and not the last character.

Comment: Thank you for all the information :)
Could you just check my answer to see if that is accurate in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using `self.endIndex.predecessor()` to remove from `result` won't effect `self` (the "given" String).

The index is just an abstraction of a number. That number is based off the string `self`, rather than `result`

But ultimately, that index is used to remove from `result`, not from `self`.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance :) Could you check my answer to see if that is is accurate?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what's happening, which indeed results into the conclusion that it's quite idiotic to use the index of self.. ?

```
result.removeAtIndex(self.endIndex.predecessor()) // <-- Stupid move
    // self.endIndex = 35
    // self.endIndex predecessor = 34 ( last index in self )
    // Removes index 34 out of result
    // result.endIndex = 36
    // results.endIndex predecessor = 35 ( the " " )
    // Removes the one before the " " inside results
```

Comment: This is basically correct. You can print the difference using `print(self.startIndex.distanceTo(self.endIndex))` and `print(result.startIndex.distanceTo(result.endIndex))`.